# Why is the Winter Bash chatroom not linked to this site?

Tags: discussion, chat, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

The [Winter Bash chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86686/winter-bash-2018-edition) is not linked to a particular site, so there are no hats available for getting a star on New Year's Eve.

In my opinion, it should be linked to this site (i.e., Meta Stack Exchange).

Answer (score 5):

No, it should not (at least not for the sole purpose of getting hats). Winter Bash is not *specific* to Meta Stack Exchange; it's something that affects all sites. Q&A about hats is centered here, yes, but it's on-topic on all per-site metas, too. If it was really tied to Meta Stack Exchange, it should be on [Meta Stack Exchange's own chat server](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/). At the moment, there's [only one room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=meta.stackexchange.com) on the main chat with Meta Stack Exchange as parent.

Stack Exchange chat has a tradition of starring 'Happy New Year' messages; it should not be too hard to find a willing audience :)

Comment: :-) Already found an audience (but my main sites have low chat activity; usually and right now)